# Python code to count the lines between any given time range

Tags: python-3.x, logging, count

Using

```
sed -ne '/13:40:47/,/13:41:48/p' ABCD.log | wc -l
```

on terminal right now to get the result.

Sample log format:

```
10.0.0.0 - - [29/Apr/2020:00:00:54 -0400]
10.0.0.0 - - [29/Apr/2020:00:00:59 -0400]
10.0.0.0 - - [29/Apr/2020:00:01:03 -0400]
10.0.0.0 - - [29/Apr/2020:00:01:05 -0400]
10.0.0.0 - - [29/Apr/2020:00:01:09 -0400]
10.0.0.0 - - [29/Apr/2020:00:01:11 -0400]
10.0.0.0 - - [29/Apr/2020:00:01:18 -0400]
10.0.0.0 - - [29/Apr/2020:00:01:24 -0400]
10.0.0.0 - - [29/Apr/2020:00:01:33 -0400]
```

I am looking to get output as below if searched between `10.0.0.0 - - [29/Apr/2020:00:01:05 -0400]` and `10.0.0.0 - - [29/Apr/2020:00:01:24 -0400]`.

```
10.0.0.0 - - [29/Apr/2020:00:01:09 -0400]
10.0.0.0 - - [29/Apr/2020:00:01:11 -0400]
10.0.0.0 - - [29/Apr/2020:00:01:18 -0400]
```

Comment: Please show your code and what you have tried and what is not working so that people can help you.

Comment: able to join nodes but count search not working.
import glob 
read_files = glob.glob("/location/*/*_log.2020-04-28.txt")
# print ( read_files)
pathfile = "/save/result.txt"
with open(pathfile, "wb") as outfile:
    # print(pathfile)
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
start_time = input("Enter start time: ")
end_time = input("Enter end time: ")
def between(l1,start_time,end_time):
    l2 = []
    for i in l1:
        if(i > start_time and i < end_time):
            l2.append(i)
    return l2

Answer (score 0):

Just read the file's line and return the lines b/w the two matching lines (start & end).See [Files I/O](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) and [Loops](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops).

Comment: Need to search and count data between time slots from 50 nodes . able to join nodes to create single out file for search.

Comment: I haven't worked with but what my common logic says is that you should search all those 50 files and append the matching lines to a result files (which contains matching results of all 50). That will be less memory consuming too.

& I'll edit my answer to give an example for matching lines in files...

Comment: @shilpi If you are using 'wb' & 'rb' for writing and reading with binary, use w+b and r+b instead ( [see this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/file-operation) )

Answer (score 0):

This logic is not working :

```
start_time = input("Enter start time: ")
end_time = input("Enter end time: ")
def between(l1,start_time,end_time):
    l2 = []
    for i in l1:
        if(i > start_time and i < end_time):
            l2.append(i)
    return l2
```